# NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION while implement fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I am new to android programming. I follow a video from youtube but i keep getting the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference error at line49`

May i know what cause the problem?

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView tv_title;
Button btn_profile, btn_notification, btn_option;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabItem tabNews, tabScrim, tabTeam, tabReport;
mainadapter mmainadapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_profile = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_profile);
    btn_notification = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_notification);
    btn_option = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_option);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabNews = findViewById(R.id.tabMain);
    tabScrim = findViewById(R.id.tabScrim);
    tabTeam = findViewById(R.id.tabTeam);
    tabReport = findViewById(R.id.tabReport);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mmainadapter = new mainadapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),     tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mmainadapter);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new     TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); <<<<49
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab 
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

}
}

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scrimmagesystem, PID: 20764
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:396)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:391)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:107)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1224)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
        at com.example.scrimmagesystem.main$1.onTabSelected(main.java:49)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1608)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1601)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1569)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1874)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2059)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

thanks in advance !

Note: too much code was written to be able to edit.
More explanations are required if too much code is written
More explanations are required if too much code is written

Comment: The error only appear when i click the 2nd tab. First tab is fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `addOnTabSelectedListener` on `TabLayout` as you're already setting it with `ViewPager` by calling this line of code:

```java
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```